# Thank editors by rewarding +2 or +5 rep

Tags: discussion, feature-request, reputation, suggested-edits

Would it be feasible and possible to have a 'Thank' button to thank editors to your question. When the OP 'thanks' an editor, the editor will get +2 or +5 rep from the OP.

This would recognise the efforts of editors who made your question or answer better. Since comments do not allow such remarks, the best way to thank them is to award them some rep for their efforts.

The OP has the choice to thank an editor since it's a way to express thanks.

Is this feasible?

Comment: why do you think it necessary? Do you have evidene that lots of bad edits are occurring or lots of bad posts are not being edited when they should be? Is this in addition to the +2 rep that we give to those with non-edit privileges for a successful edit or to replace that?

Comment: +5 for edit is too high!

Comment: People already get +2 until they reach 2k rep.

Comment: @RobertLongson No, it's mainly to thank them for their efforts in making a post better

Comment: @Helmar That's ***until*** they reach 2k rep

Comment: Very related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/182724/award-reputation-to-an-editor-when-edited-post-receives-next-upvote

Answer (score 10):

**I disagree.**

Your idea might sound gracious to all those contributors who try to make posts as clear and useful as possible. But the entire reputation points awarded on Stack Exchange have been designed to encourage more useful questions and answers than edits giving ten points to useful answers and five points to well-researched and useful questions.

I don't think it is fair to give the same reputation points SE awards to a questioner to an editor because:

1. Making an edit doesn't require as much time and effort as asking a well-researched and useful question.
2. It will encourage more edits than it would have with two reputation points. Worse, it will encourage reputation hounds to be more involved in editing than necessary just to earn reputations leading to some unnecessary trivial edits.
3. The worst case scenario would be a situation where, not very likely though, sockpuppets using this feature to gain more reputation points.

I think giving two reputation points until they reach 2,000 rep points is fair and works fine.

Comment: +1 I also estimate this feature's implementation would increase useless edits. When I make a perfect edit, it's not because I'm incentivized by any gamification aspects. I just want to help.

Comment: @M.A.R. The reputation is only rewarded if the OP wants to, the OP can choose not to reward it

Comment: @luweiqi More often than not, a post is much more improved by a very helpful comment than an edit. If you award a thank you reputation for someone's edit efforts, how about awarding it for helpful comments? I understand your intention, but I don't think it will be that effective. Also, you need to note that many people including myself don't edit for reputation points. We do it just to improve the quality of a site.

Answer (score 9):

I'm not sure how useful this would be. However, if this *was* implemented, I think the "thanker" should have to pay the 5 reputation from his or her own reputation. So -5 to the thanker, +5 to the thanked. That would make sure people only did it when they truly meant it. I guess that would be alright.