# Additional incentive (badges or rep) for *high-quality* edits

Tags: discussion, reputation, edits, badges

First off, [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/278/244644) (from 2009) is similar to mine but I believe it is not a duplicate: I am aware that these days, we don't have a problem with too few people editing posts. If anything, we should be encouraging high-quality edits, and maybe even actively discourage unhelpful edits (not entirely sure about that, but it's also not what this question is about).

So I am wondering whether it would make sense/be a good idea to try and encourage people to make their edits *meaningful* by providing some sort of additional incentive that goes beyond the 2 rep points users with < 2000 rep can earn from getting a suggested edit approved. For instance, users could e.g.

- earn a small amount of additional rep every time a post they edited gets upvoted
- earn a badge if the number of upvotes for a certain number of posts increases significantly (doubles/triples/crosses a certain threshold etc.) after they edited them

Beyond encouraging people to be thorough when editing posts, attaching some sort of long-term benefits to great edits would also be a way of saying

> "We acknowledge that even though you are not the original author of this post, your contribution played an important role in it becoming a valuable resource for the community."

---

What's your take on this? And, if something like this were to be implemented, what (**if any!**) would be the criteria for identifying "meaningful" edits?

Comment: Similar: [Badge for editing a negative vote post that goes on to be a positive scoring post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/111396/badge-for-editing-a-negative-vote-post-that-goes-on-to-be-a-positive-scoring-pos) and [Should there be a badge for awesome edits on questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44582/should-there-be-a-badge-for-awesome-edits-on-questions) and [Adding incentive for editing](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/278/adding-incentive-for-editing)

Comment: ..and [Let me reward a good edit on my question/answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36574/let-me-reward-a-good-edit-on-my-question-answer) and [Give a badge to users who improve closed questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/109543/give-a-badge-to-users-who-improve-closed-questions) and [Rep for heroic edits](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/111153/rep-for-heroic-edits) and [Reputation sharing after a post edit](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/209902/reputation-sharing-after-a-post-edit) and I'm sure I'm missing some.

Comment: and here's a few more I missed: [Editors should get points for up votes](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82425/editors-should-get-points-for-up-votes) and ['assist rep' after edit](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114215/assist-rep-after-edit), plus the sidebar has some more --->

Comment: I'm not quite sure that's a correlation you can determine. For one, the up-votes may have happened without your edit. There are also cases where multiple people have edited prior to any up-votes - who gets credit then? How could the system decide? You can't use number of characters or other similar metrics because it is quite easy to add two paragraphs of hot air, and someone else to add one sentence that really helps the post.

Comment: I like the flavor of your idea "earn a small amount of additional rep every time a post they edited gets upvoted" - But at the same time, it might lead to extra gamification. So I would cap the extra rep at 2 points max. Just so people don't abuse it

Comment: As long as we reject tiny edits as "too minor", we're helping out those who _do_ make proper, substantive edits.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there's really a way for the system to automatically reward an edit in any way - there really isn't a strong enough correlation between the edit itself and any subsequent up-votes. I just don't see how the system can make an assumption that the two are related at all (with the added complication that occurs when multiple people have edited a post, which is quite common).

Personally, I edit usually because I can't stand to look at poorly-worded, poorly-tagged or poorly-formatted questions. I never got into that - at all - when I was low enough rep where it would have mattered. But I've never done it for badges or any other accolades, and the existence of an additional badge would not encourage me to edit more (or improve my editing skills). That's just one person, but I doubt I'm alone.

I do remember making some pretty substantial edits to questions in really bad shape, and a few times I've received comments - not from the OP, but fellow editors I respect - along the lines of "amazing edit!" That is way more reward for me than some system-generated badge that nobody else might even notice.